# Isomorphism between Projective Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have some questions about some conclusions in the proof of Prop. 3.1.9 in Liu's "Algebraic Geometry" (page 82 and 52):

Here the main proof:

[image]

...and the used lemmata 2.3.38 & 2.3.40:

[image]

My two questions (refer to the red tagged box):

1. Why $\phi(B_+)E$ is equal to $E_+$? (In this case we would have $V_+(\phi(B_+)E) = V_+(E_+) =0$, so according to 2.3.40 $Proj E = Proj E  \backslash V_+(\phi(B_+)E) \to Proj B$ would be indeed well defined)
2. Why Prop. 2.3.38 provides the existence of $Pro jE \to SpecC$?

Comment: 1. Note that $C$ is just an algebra over $A$ and thus $E_+ = B_+ \otimes_A C$. I donot see any problem there. 2. Now $B \otimes_A C$ is a graded $C$ algebra. Thus hypothesis of propostion is satisfied. Thus $Proj(B \otimes_A C)$ becomes a scheme over $Spec(C)$ and the morphism is exactly the structure morphism.